# Viscous and pressure regime of sphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag

I came across a lecture in which the resistance force on a sphere [image]
.It mentions that if velocity is less than critical velocity, the flow will in viscous regime.
But my doubt is pressure term(second term) has square of velocity and thus pressure regime should dominates for any velocity irrespective of critical velocity??

Please clarify/help on this.

Comment: Take the ratio of the two terms: $\frac{C_2rV}{C_1}$. Your claim is essentially that this number is always much greater than one. But that depends entirely on the relative values of $C_1$, $C_2$, $r$, and $V$. With no additional information, the claim isn't convincing.

Comment: There is no critical velocity for flow past a sphere, and, in addition, the equation you gave for the drag force on a sphere is not correct.